# Some Javascript code not working, only jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an external javascript file where I wrote jquery code and javascript code but the javascript code isn't working. Only the alert is working.

I want some texts to flash different colors but it doesn't.

When I inspect elements using `ctrl+shift+i` I see the colors changing under inspect element, but it doesn't change in the webpage.

Something like it's running on the background or what I really don't know.

```js
function flash() { var text = document.getElementById('sales'); text.style.color=(text.style.color=='red')? 'green' : 'red'; } var clr = setInterval(flash, 500)
```

```html
<p id="sales"> <h3 style ="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;"> Flash Sales </h3></p>
```

Comment: We need to see some code.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] contain all relevant HTML, css and js code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: I have posted some codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you properly check the inspection, you'll see that your HTML was changed from what you have. A `<p>` element cannot contain a `<h3>` element, and the DOM has been changed to `<p id="sales"></p><h3>...</h3>`.

As such, your CSS is being applied to the wrong place.

```js
function flash() { var text = document.getElementById('sales'); text.style.color=(text.style.color=='red')? 'green' : 'red'; } var clr = setInterval(flash, 500)
```

```html
<h3 id="sales" style ="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;"> Flash Sales </h3>
```

Comment: `If you properly check the inspection, you'll see that your HTML was changed` that's a bit inaccurate, you don't inspect HTML there but the resulting DOM.

Comment: Yes, I realised that the problem is from the <h3> tag so I removed it and applied styling in the css and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by removing the in-line styling all the way from the <h3 tag and styled it in css.

Answer (score -1):

In pure java script

```js
document.querySelector('element name').style.color = 'red';
```

In jquery

```js
$('element name').css({red : 'red'});
```

Comment: This is the code in html: <p id="sales"> <h3 style ="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;"> Flash Sales </h3></p>

Comment: This doesn't explain the JS code that you have a problem with because you haven't added that to the question. @Skynet. We can't debug code we can't see.

Comment: And this is the javascript code: function flash() {                         var text = document.getElementById('sales');                                                          text.style.color=(text.style.color=='red')? 'green' : 'red';                         }  var clr = setInterval(flash, 500);

Comment: Please how do I separate lines here on stackoverflow because when I click enter on my phone keyboard it just posts whatever I'm typing